# How can I create a hyperlink list directing to a specific page in a pdf file?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, hyperlink

I have a very long PDF file (over 1000 pages scanned document). I want to create a keyword list with over 2000 hyperlinks, which can direct me to certain pages in the PDF quickly by clicking the page.

Example:

```
Keyword list

Word   Page(hyperlink)
abc    P560
def    P124    P223
ghi    P49
jkl    P980    P1023   P32
...    ...
```

So far I can open any page in Chrome as shown below. But how I can make them into hyperlinks in the list? Is it even possible to do it in Excel? Should I try an HTML file?

```
Sub test()

  Dim chromePath, filePath, pageNum As String

  chromePath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
  filePath = " file:///C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/textbook.pdf"
  pageNum = "#page=2"

  Shell (chromePath & filePath & pageNum)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can create a hyperlink formula, calling a function which to call Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

1. Copy the next code in a standard module, to create a Hyperlink formula (here in "A1" of the active sheet):

```
'Hyperlink function to call macro____________________________________
Sub testCreateHyperlinkFunction()
  Dim chromePath, filePath, pageNum As String
  chromePath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
  
  filePath = "file:\\\C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\textbook.pdf""
  pageNum = "#page=2"
       'Very important to have # in front of the function name!
       Range("A1").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#OpenPdfPageClick()"", """ & chromePath & "|" & filePath & pageNum & """)"
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next function code in the same module:

```
Function OpenPdfPageClick()
   Set OpenPdfPageClick = Selection
   Dim arr: arr = Split(Selection.Value, "|")
   Shell Chr(34) & arr(0) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & arr(1) & Chr(34)
End Function
```

3. Run the first code to create the link and then click in "A1" cell of the active sheet, where you can see the created link.

The same function can be called from cells with different pdf files full name. I tried showing a way to also supply to the function the Chrome full path, but all of them being run by Chrome, its full name can be placed in a `Constant` inside the function code and pass only the pdf full name.

Since the Chrome installation folder can be different from user to user, a function to extract it from Registry can also be implemented. In fact, I will also post such a function:

```
Function getChromeExePath(strExeApp As String) As String
  Dim WSHShell As Object: Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  getChromeExePath = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" & strExeApp & "\")
End Function
```

It can be called in the above `Sub`, creating the link in the next way:

Instead of:

```
chromePath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

you can use:

```
chromePath = getChromeExePath("chrome.exe")
```

Test it and send some feedback, please. I tested it (with one of my files) and it works as is should.

Comment: @sebastian wei Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it work as you need?